# What type of function is $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know it's not a rational function because the numerator is not a polynomial. I don't think it's a root function because there's an $x$ in the denominator that's not a root. I could re-express the function as $f(x)=(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}x^{-1}-x^{-1}$, or $f(x)=x^{-1}\left[(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\right]$, but I don't believe it's a power function because it can't be expressed in the form $f(x)=kx^a$ ($x$ raised to a single exponent), though it does resemble some sort of algebraic "product" of power functions I suppose.

Comment: It's most naturally called an _algebraic function_ : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah, so it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most naturally called an [*algebraic function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function), as it can be expressed as a root of a polynomial equation in $f$ and $x$ by simple transformations:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x} \\
xf(x) =\sqrt{x+1}-1 \\
xf(x)+1 = \sqrt{x+1} \\
\left(xf(x)+1\right)^2=x+1 \\
x^2f(x)^2+2xf(x)+1 = x+1 \\
x^2f(x)^2+2xf(x)-x = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. It is none of the types of functions you listed. This is an example of an algebraic function. Algebraic functions are functions in $x$ which can be expressed using operations we'd 'normall'y use to solve equations, i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, powers, and taking roots.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+1}+1$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}$ and for large $x$,   $f(x) \sim x^{-0.5}$.

Comment: I assume "counter" is a synonym for "numerator"? And your point is that for large $x$, the function behaves like a power function?

Comment: Yes thanks, I was too sloppy. Edited it. And yes your remark is right. Although it appears as some "weird" function, it is close to something familiar from a calculus standpoint of view. From an algebraic point of view, the function is just an element of the field $\mathbb{R}(\sqrt{x+1})$, which is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}(x)$ of degree 2. –